# Evitar introducir datos que no corresponden

Tags: php, mysql

estoy trabajando con php/mysql, y a la hora de insertar datos, me permite ingresar información la cual no debe de corresponder o no debería de dejarme que introduzca dichos datos, por ejemplo, debo introducir el nombre de una persona y apellido, si introduzco en el nombre un 1 y en el apellido otro 1, pues ingresa esos datos tomándolos como correctos, ¿hay alguna forma de evitar esto?, pues me deja introducir números, sin embargo, es algo que quiero evitar. Os paso el código que estoy trabajando.

```html
<?php

require_once('Ninos.php');
$modeloNinos = new Ninos();

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    //PASAMOS LOS DATOS
    $datosNino = [];
    $datosNino['nombre'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nombre', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $datosNino['apellido'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'apellido', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $datosNino['nacimiento']= date("Y/m/d", strtotime($_POST['nacimiento']));
    $datosNino['comportamiento'] = $_POST['comportamiento'];
    try 
    {
        //LLAMAMOS Y REALIZAMOS LA INSERCIÓN DE DATOS
        $id = $modeloNinos->insert($datosNino);
        if ((int) $id) 
        {
            $mensajeOK = 'EXITO: Niño nuevo añadido a la base de datos';
            header('Refresh: 1; URL=indexNinos.php');
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception $ex) 
    {
        $mensajeKO = $ex->getMessage();
    }
}

?>
<!--CREAMOS EL HTML-->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
       <?php echo Utils::getHead('Alta Niño'); ?>
       <link href="assets/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Estonia&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--ALMACENAMOS LOS DATOS-->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-6 col-md-4 offset-md-4 mt-4">
                    <h1 class="text-center mt-4 bg-secondary rounded-pill">Alta Niño</h1>
                    <!--Si ha tenido exito-->
                    <?php if (isset($mensajeOK)) { ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            <?php echo $mensajeOK; ?>
                        </div>
                    <!--Si no ha tenido exito-->
                    <?php } else if (isset($mensajeKO)) { ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                            <?php echo $mensajeKO; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <!--CREAMOS EL FORMULARIO-->
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 offset-md-4">
                    <form action="crearNinos.php" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group text-white rounded">
                            <label for="nombre" class="bg-dark w-100 rounded">Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingresa nombre" required />
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-white">
                            <label for="apellido" class="bg-dark w-100 rounded">Apellido</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Ingresa apellido" required />
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-white">
                            <label for="nacimiento" class="bg-dark w-100 rounded">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nacimiento" name="nacimiento" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" required />
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-white rounded">
                            <label for="comportamiento" class="bg-dark w-100 rounded">Bueno/Malo</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="2" id="comportamiento" name="comportamiento" placeholder="Bueno = Sí / Malo = No" required />
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right text-dark w-50 mb-2"><i class="bi bi-plus"></i> Crear</button>
                        <a href="indexNinos.php" class="btn btn-warning float-right mb-2 w-50"><i class="bi bi-arrow-left"></i> Cancelar</a>
                        </div> 
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar la función `preg_replace` de `php` combinado con una expresión regular que permita eliminar los números de la cadena de caracteres.

```
$nombre = "D0n Qu1jote de la Manch4";
echo preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $nombre );
```

El primer parámetro es la expresión regular que contiene los números del cero al nueve, el segundo parámetro es el caracter por el que se deben reemplazar los números y el tercer parámetro es el string original.

Para el ejemplo, la salida sería:

```
Dn Qujote de la Manch
```

[Aquí tienes la docu oficial de `preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php)